# SKIP FAIL to ignore only part of match

Tags: regex, preg-match, pcre

I've recently learned that using  `(*SKIP)(*F)` help to remove unwanted match.

For example for the following text :

```
<div>
[text1]
 <div>

[text2]
 </div>
[text3]
</div>
[text4]
```

in case if I would like to find only text between `[` and `]` (with those characters) that is not inside between `<div>` and `</div>` (so result should be only text4 I could use the following PCRE:

```
/<div>.*<\/div>(*SKIP)(*F)|(\[\w+\])/gs
```

and that's fine.

The question is - is it possible use this technique somehow to remove only some groups of match on the left site?

Let's assume that I would like to remove find find only text between `[` and `]` (with those characters) that is not inside between `<div>` and `</div>` that are inside other `<div>..</div>` pair.

So for the previous text I would like only match `text1`, `text3` and `text4` and text2 not because it's inside div nested inside other div.

Is it possible do to it using the same technique?

To find this text I can simply use:

```
/<div>.*<div>(.*)<\/div>.*<\/div>/gs
```

But when I use:

```
/<div>.*<div>(.*)<\/div>.*<\/div>(*SKIP)(*F)|(\[\w+\])/gs
```

I still get only `text4` as match and not other texts - [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jQ6uC6/1).

If not is there any other easy technique to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to be looking pretty but this is the only way I could make it work. Here is the working regex:

```
~<div>(?:(?!</div>).)*?(\[.*?\])(?:(?!</div>).)*?<div>.*?</div>.*?(\[.*?\]).*?</div>|<div>.*?(\[.*?\]).*?</div>|(\[.*?\])~s
```

And your text is captured in all matched groups.

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jQ6uC6/2)

Answer (score 1):

Just try the below regex to match `text1`, `text3`, `text4`,

```
(?s)<div>(?:(?!<div>).)*?<\/div>(*SKIP)(*F)|\[\K[^\]]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sQ0kW4/8)

Using the `s` modifier, the above regex would match the `<div>` tag block which don't contain the string `<div>`, so the below block would be matched.

```
 <div>

[text2]
 </div>
```

`(*SKIP)(*F)` in the pattern makes the match to Fail. Now the pattern in the right side of `|` symbol , (in our case its `\[\K[^\]]*`) would be matched against the remaining input.

Comment: [Did you check this demo](http://regex101.com/r/jQ6uC6/3). I believe it need to find `[text5]` also.